# Python Generator object at location print statement when trying to remove repeats from the list

Tags: python

I am working on a text-based adventure game for my course and I am having a really difficult time removing repeated items from a list. I am getting print lines that say `[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001DF76F37510>]` . I am not sure what I did, just that it in line 93. I am just now learning python and I'm only in week 8 so please be aware that I am still learning terminology. Here is my code:

```
import time
from typing import Set, Union

delay = 0.5

# evaluation strategy, call by object sharing. modify list w/room. to append items to bag.
def item(b_list):
   l = b_list.append(items_bag[current_location])
   print("Your Bag: {}".format(l))

# Function to output welcome message prompt and collect user name.
def welcome_message(player_name):
   message = "Hi {}, Welcome to Escape the Children. This is a text-based\n" \
                     "adventure game. You must successfully navigate through the home,\n" \
                     "without encountering the children. If the children see you its game over.\n" \
                     "In order to win, you must make it back to the front door, with all six items.".format(player_name)
   print(message)

# Function to output game instructions
def game_instructions(player_name):
   instructions = "In order to move through the rooms of the home, type in chosen\n" \
                       "direction. You can choose to go north (n), south (s), east (e), west (w).\n" \
                       "{}, enter quit (q) at any time to exit the game.\n".format(player_name)
   print(instructions)



# This dict gives each room a string, that informs user of room. I used integers for readability
player_location = {0: "You are at the front Door.",
                   1: "You are in the Living Room.",
                   2: "You are in the Bathroom.",
                   3: "You are in the Kitchen.",
                   4: "The children have you spotted you in the Dining Room. \nGAME OVER!",
                   5: "You are in the Master Bedroom.",
                   6: "You are in the Playroom.",
                   7: "You are in the Mudroom.",
                   8: "You are in the Second Bedroom.",
                   9: "You have Quit the game. See you next time."}

#This dictionary links each room (using a number) to original location and available directions and links to next room
rooms = {0: {"N": 1, "S": 2, "W": 5, "E":7, "Q": 9},
         1: {"N": 3, "S": 0, "Q": 9},
         2: {"N":0, "S": 4, "Q": 9},
         3: {"S": 1, "Q": 9},
         4: {"I'm Sorry! \n": 4},
         5: {"E": 0, "W":6, "Q": 9},
         6: {"E": 5, "Q": 9},
         7: {"W": 0, "E": 8, "Q": 9},
         8: {"W": 7, "Q": 9},
         9: {"Q": 9} }

# dict of vocabulary player can enter, into game.
vocab = {"QUIT":  "Q",
         "NORTH": "N",
         "SOUTH": "S",
         "EAST":  "E",
         "WEST":  "W"}
# dict of bag items
items_bag = {0: "",
              1: "Keys",
              2: "Wallet",
              3: "Phone",
              4: "",
              5: "Glasses",
              6: "Laptop",
              7: "Coffee",
              8: "",
              9: ""}

#list of bag items
test_bag = ["Keys", "Wallet", "Phone", "Glasses", "Laptop", "Coffee"]



# collect user data
name = input("Enter your name: ").capitalize()
welcome_message(name)
time.sleep(delay)
print("~" * 40)
time.sleep(delay)
game_instructions(name)
print("~" * 40)
b = []

current_location = 0
while True:
   # Joins the room dict keys and concatenates a string to loop through the available_exits and add direction and a "'".
   available_exits = ", ".join(rooms[current_location].keys())
   time.sleep(delay)
   print(player_location[current_location]) # Calls the current location key's value, from the locations.
   # add items to the bag using the location as the key, calling th value of same key in items dict. sent to list
   # also removes duplicates from the list
   b.append(items_bag[current_location] for x in test_bag if x not in b )



   # print("You have added the following items in your bag: {}".format(b))
   print("You have the following items in your bag: {}".format(b))



   # If the current_location is 4 (Dining room w/ villains) terminate loop.
# If current location is 9 (Quit game) terminate loop.
   if current_location == 4:
      break
   if current_location == 9:
      break

# Prompt player to input desired direction into game. Provide player with available_exits (line 37). Force upper-case.
   direction = input("Available directions are: " + available_exits + " \n").upper()
   time.delay = 1

# if the player input is longer than 1 character, split it into a list. Then parse list through vocab dict. For speed.
   if len(direction) > 1:
      words = direction.split()
      for word in words:
         if word in vocab:
            direction = vocab[word]
            break
# if the players chosen direction is in the rooms dict it will print out the room dicts key, value along with
# providing the player wit ha prompt to chose another direction and allowing input.
   if direction in rooms[current_location]:
      current_location = rooms[current_location][direction]

   else:
      print("Choose a valid direction")
```

is there a better way to do this:
[image]

Comment: `b.append(items_bag[current_location] for x in test_bag if x not in b )` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: You probably mean to write: `b.append([items_bag[current_location] for x in test_bag if x not in b] )` or  `b.extend([items_bag[current_location] for x in test_bag if x not in b] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't do what you want because `items_bag[current_location] for x in test_bag if x not in b` is a generator expression. Since you're not iterating over it, you're just adding an iterator to the `b` list, not anything useful.

I think you want something like this:

```
if items_bag[current_location] not in b:
    b.append(items_bag[current_location])
```

I'm not using `test_bag` in this code, but I don't *think* you need it, though it's not entirely clear what the logic of your code is supposed to be. I think you're supposed to be picking up each item you come across (one per room) automatically.

Do note that with my code, the empty strings that you're using for rooms that don't contain anything will be treated the same as the other strings, and will get added to `b` the first time you visit an "empty" room. To avoid that, you'd probably need to add another check that the room isn't empty (e.g. `if items_bag[current_location] != '' and items_bag[current_location] not in b:...`).

Another approach might be better if you might want to have rooms with multiple items, rather than either nothing or one item. You could make the values of the `items_bag` dictionary into lists, and an empty list would indicate an empty room. The code you'd need to use when visiting the room would be a little more complicated, since you'd need a loop, but it's still not too bad:

```
# above:
items_bag = { 1: [], 2: ["Keys", "Wallet"] } # example contents

# below, in the main loop
for item in items_bag[current_location]:
    if item not in b:
        b.append(item)
```

You could also consider using a `set` for `b`, rather than a list. Sets efficiently avoid duplicate values, using hashtables, so you could just unconditionally add all the items from a room to the set and let its internal workings sort out any duplication. The downside is that sets are unordered, so you'd get the items in an arbitrary, and possibly changing order in any iteration over `b`.